# Can you provide a list of objects that needs to be disposed in SharePoint?

Tags: dispose

I need a list of SharePoint objects which need to be disposed.

This is for code analysis purpose. I have got a code review today and want a quick list of the objects to look out for in the code.

**UPDATE**
Here is what to dispose and what not to dispose, if there is anything more to add then kindly advise:-

Dispose the SPWeb obtained by iterating over the Site.AllWebs collection

SPC110201: Dispose created SPSite objects

SPC110203: Dispose SPWeb objects created with SPSite.OpenWeb

SPC110204: Dispose SPSite objects created with SPSite.SelfServiceCreateSite

SPC110205: Dispose SPWeb created by SPLimitedWebPartManager

SPC110211: Dispose SPSite created by SPSiteCollection.Add

SPC110212: Dispose SPSite created by SPSiteCollection[] index operator

SPC110213: Dispose SPWeb created by SPWebCollection.Add

SPC110214: Dispose SPWeb created by SPWebCollection[] index operator

SPC110231: Do not dispose SPListEventProperties.Web

SPC110232: Do not dispose SPWebEventProperties.Web

SPC110233: Do not dispose SPItemEventProperties.Web

SPC110234: Do not dispose SPItemEventProperties.ListItem.Web

SPC110235: Do not dispose SPItemEventProperties.Web.Site

SPC110236: Do not dispose SPItemEventProperties.ListItem.Web.Site

SPC110237: Do not dispose SPFeatureReceiverProperties.Feature.Parent

SPC110241: Do not dispose SPSite.RootWeb

SPC110242: Do not dispose SPWeb.ParentWeb

SPC110243: Do not dispose SPList.ParentWeb

SPC110244: Do not dispose SPSite returned by SPControl.GetContextSite

SPC110245: Do not dispose SPWeb returned by SPControl.GetContextWeb

SPC110246: Do not dispose SPSite returned by SPContext.Current.Site

SPC110247: Do not dispose SPWeb returned by SPContext.Current.Web

SPC110261: Close PublishingWeb created by PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWebs[] index operator

SPC110262: Close PublishingWeb created by PublishingWeb.GetVariation

SPC110263: Close PublishingWeb created by PublishingWebCollection.Add

SPC110281: Dispose SPSite created with UserProfiles.PersonalSite

Reference: http://docs.spcaf.com/v4/SPCAF_VISITORGROUP_RULES_MEMORYDISPOSALGROUP.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SPWeb
SPSite

The web in SPLimitedWebPartManager 
The site in UserProfiles.PersonalSite
```

Also for publishing webs, closing:

```
Close PublishingWeb created by PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWebs[] index operator
Close PublishingWeb created by PublishingWeb.GetVariation
Close PublishingWeb created by PublishingWebCollection.Add
```

from http://docs.spcaf.com/v4/SPCAF_VISITORGROUP_RULES_MEMORYDISPOSALGROUP.html

Dispose guidelines: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973248(v=office.12).aspx

What not to dispose : http://ankursharepoint.blogspot.com/2012/11/sharepoint-2010-do-not-dispose-guidance.html

More great information:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rogerla/archive/2008/02/12/sharepoint-2007-and-wss-3-0-dispose-patterns-by-example.aspx

Comment: http://docs.spcaf.com/v4/SPCAF_VISITORGROUP_RULES_MEMORYDISPOSALGROUP.html Add this to the list

Comment: According to link from @variable one should also dispose of `PublishingWeb` in some cases (in addition to `SPWeb`)

Comment: Added those to the list.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is what to dispose and what not to dispose:-**

Dispose the SPWeb obtained by iterating over the Site.AllWebs collection

SPC110201: Dispose created SPSite objects

SPC110203: Dispose SPWeb objects created with SPSite.OpenWeb

SPC110204: Dispose SPSite objects created with SPSite.SelfServiceCreateSite

SPC110205: Dispose SPWeb created by SPLimitedWebPartManager

SPC110211: Dispose SPSite created by SPSiteCollection.Add

SPC110212: Dispose SPSite created by SPSiteCollection[] index operator

SPC110213: Dispose SPWeb created by SPWebCollection.Add

SPC110214: Dispose SPWeb created by SPWebCollection[] index operator

SPC110231: Do not dispose SPListEventProperties.Web

SPC110232: Do not dispose SPWebEventProperties.Web

SPC110233: Do not dispose SPItemEventProperties.Web

SPC110234: Do not dispose SPItemEventProperties.ListItem.Web

SPC110235: Do not dispose SPItemEventProperties.Web.Site

SPC110236: Do not dispose SPItemEventProperties.ListItem.Web.Site

SPC110237: Do not dispose SPFeatureReceiverProperties.Feature.Parent

SPC110241: Do not dispose SPSite.RootWeb

SPC110242: Do not dispose SPWeb.ParentWeb

SPC110243: Do not dispose SPList.ParentWeb

SPC110244: Do not dispose SPSite returned by SPControl.GetContextSite

SPC110245: Do not dispose SPWeb returned by SPControl.GetContextWeb

SPC110246: Do not dispose SPSite returned by SPContext.Current.Site

SPC110247: Do not dispose SPWeb returned by SPContext.Current.Web

SPC110261: Close PublishingWeb created by PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWebs[] index operator

SPC110262: Close PublishingWeb created by PublishingWeb.GetVariation

SPC110263: Close PublishingWeb created by PublishingWebCollection.Add

SPC110281: Dispose SPSite created with UserProfiles.PersonalSite

Reference: http://docs.spcaf.com/v4/SPCAF_VISITORGROUP_RULES_MEMORYDISPOSALGROUP.html

Answer (score 1):

I want to add to the two lists above

Dispose the `SPWeb` obtained by iterating over the `Site.AllWebs` collection